# Inner classes with the same name as an outer class?

Tags: java, inner-classes

#### Constraints:

> I have a maven source code generator that I wrote that is creating POJO classes
>   from some data files that have nested namespaces. I want each namespace to
>   be nested as an inner class. In some cases out of my control I end up
>   with inner classes that are the same simple name as the outermost
>   class.
>
> All the classes must be `public` scope as this is for a type safe
>   wrapper over something like a properties file, but hierarchical..
>
> I can't change the names otherwise I am changing the names meaning and the namespace
>   that is enclosing data.

#### Given than I have the following code:

```
public class A
{
    public class B
    {
        public class A
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Inner classes should append the name of the outer class to form a unique namespace such as `A$B$A.class`, I haven't found a valid reason for this not to compile.

**Is there any trick to get this to compile?**

Comment: For god sake: why? And AFAIK, nope.

Comment: For all the answerers saying "Don't Do That Then": This is an interesting theoretical question, and "it doesn't work" isn't especially responsive.

Comment: What constraints are there on the trick? One obvious trick is "rename it", but I doubt you want that. What properties should be true of the result for a trick to be considered valid?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No. [From the JLS section on class declarations:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1)

> It is a compile-time error if a class has the same simple name as any of its enclosing classes or interfaces.

*Note: I somehow managed to miss this on my first pass through looking for an explicit rule. Check the edit history if you want the tortuous way I got here.*

Answer (score 9):

You asked: **Is there any trick to get this to compile?**.

The answer is: Well, maybe....

[image: Maze]

Create a class like the following:

```
public class A
{
    public class B
    {
        public class X
        {
        }
    }
}
```

And a class where this class is going to be used

```
public class AUse
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        A.B.X aba = new A().new B().new X();
        System.out.println("Created "+aba+" of class "+aba.getClass());
    }
}
```

Then, download the [Apache Byte Code Engineering Library (BCEL)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-bcel/), and create and run the following class:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.bcel.Repository;
import org.apache.bcel.util.BCELifier;

public class CreateCreators
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        new BCELifier(
            Repository.lookupClass("A"),
            new FileOutputStream("ACreator.java")).start();
        new BCELifier(
            Repository.lookupClass("A$B"),
            new FileOutputStream("A$BCreator.java")).start();
        new BCELifier(
            Repository.lookupClass("A$B$X"),
            new FileOutputStream("A$B$XCreator.java")).start();
        new BCELifier(
            Repository.lookupClass("AUse"),
            new FileOutputStream("AUseCreator.java")).start();
    }
}
```

This uses the `BCELifier` class from the BCEL. This is a class that takes a `.class` file, and creates a `.java` file that can be compiled to a `.class` file, that, when it is executed, creates the `.class` file that it was originally fed with. (Side note: I love this library).

So the `A$B$XCreator.java` file that is created there contains the BCEL code that is necessary to create the `A$B$X.class` file. This consists of statements like the generation of the constant pool and the instructions:

```
...
_cg = new ClassGen("A$B$X", "java.lang.Object", "A.java", 
    ACC_PUBLIC | ACC_SUPER, new String[] {  });
...
il.append(_factory.createFieldAccess("A$B$X", "this$1", 
    new ObjectType("A$B"), Constants.PUTFIELD));
```

Similarly, the `AUseCreator.java` contains the BCEL code that creates the `AUse.class`. For example, the instruction of the constructor invocation of `A$B$X':

```
...
il.append(_factory.createInvoke("A$B$X", "<init>", Type.VOID, 
    new Type[] { new ObjectType("A$B") }, Constants.INVOKESPECIAL));
```

Now you can simply replace the String occurrences of `"A$B$X"` with `"A$B$A"` in the `A$B$XCreator.java` and `AUseCreator.java`, and then compile and run these classes.

The result will be a `A$B$A.class` file, and a `AUse.class` file that uses the `A$B$A.class`. Executing the `AUse` will print

```
Created A$B$A@15f5897 of class class A$B$A
```

---

I'm not sure whether this is considered as a "trick", or whether it still can be called "compiling" at all, but there is a way, at least. The key point is here, of course, that the fact that it did not compile is solely due to a limitation of the *language*, but there is no reason why this should not be representable in form of `class` files, regardless of how they are created.

Answer (score 2):

You can't get it to compile, but more importantly, *why would you need to*?

What's wrong with:

```
public class A
{
    public class B
    {
        public class InnerA
        {

        }
    }
}
```

This seems like a design problem that you need to fix. If you can't rename it, consider anonymous inner classes. Or take some of those classes outside. Or just don't even use them.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit of a hack, but this compiles at my machine:

```
class A
{
    public class B
    {
        public class Α
        {

        }
    }
}
```

[Try it.](http://ideone.com/e7ZVak) Literally: copy-past this thing ;)

SPOILER:

> The name of the inner class is a capital letter alpha of the Greek alphabet. It's a Unicode character.

Comment: Well what if the outer A needs to be public? I mean, the question has a public outer A...

Comment: Yes, I know, but I was testing this in another Java file, and you can have only one public class. That is not the hack :) Make it public if you want to :)

Comment: This won't compile on my machine. Unicode doesn't seem to be supported... Also, that's a normal A.

Comment: I applaud your creativity but curse anyone who would actually use this on real live code.

Comment: Sadly, just a fancy way of renaming.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're after, the following might work for you:

```
public class A {
  class B extends C {
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new A().new B().new A();
  }
}

class C {
  class A {
    {
      System.out.println(getClass());
    }
  }
}
```